# Connecting kafDrop to a Secure Broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am trying run kafDrop using docker image. I am able to connect to non SSL broker by running command

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9000:9000 --network=host -e KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT=KafkaServer:9092 obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
```

But when I tried to connect to same Broker with enabling SSL using command,

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9000:9000 --network=host -e KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT=KafkaServer:9092 -e KAFKA_PROPERTIES=$(cat kafka.properties | base64) -e KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE=$(cat myTrustStore | base64) -e KAFKA_KEYSTORE=$(cat myKeyStore | base64) obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
```

getting below error

```
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error parsing reference: "bmZpZy9wb21LZXlTdG9yZQpzc2wua2V5c3RvcmUucGFzc3dvcmQ9Y2hhbmdlaXQKc3NsLmtleS5w" is not a valid repository/tag: repository name must be lowercase.
```

and if I dont use base64 in command then I am getting error

```
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error parsing reference: "ssl.keystore.location=/opt/KafdropConfig/myKeyStore" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.
```

I have copied kafka.properties, myTrustStore and myKeyStore  on the my machine where docker is running
Can you please help me to identify the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: You might have more luck raising an issue on the repo https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop/issues

Comment: I would suggest using a docker volume and the file options rather than base64...

Answer (score 0):

> not a valid repository/tag: repository name must be lowercase

This is a `docker run` error, which means your command was not escaped properly

Try adding quotes around the bash executions

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9000:9000 \
  -e KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT=KafkaServer:9092 \
  -e KAFKA_PROPERTIES="$(cat kafka.properties | base64)" \
  -e KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE="$(cat myTrustStore | base64)" \
  -e KAFKA_KEYSTORE="$(cat myKeyStore | base64)" \
   obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
```

and you can use base64 or just volume mount the files. 
https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop#connecting-to-a-secure-broker

Note: I removed `--network=host` because if you really need that, then your Kafka networking needs adjusted to allow external clients